# Why and when we use ng test command

Tags: angular, angular5

I searched and found on [git](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test) but did not understand why and when we used `ng test` command. And what does that even mean?

Comment: when you have `karma` test cases you should be using `ng test` to run them

Comment: what is karma testing? can you explain ?

Comment: please google about it and refer [**angular testing**](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

Answer (score 1):

**`ng test`** will compile the application into an output directory

Tests will execute after a build is executed via **[`Karma`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma)**, and it will automatically watch your files for changes. You can run tests a single time via --watch=false or --single-run.

You can run tests with coverage via --code-coverage. The coverage report will be in the coverage/ directory.